# If $\vec{b} \neq \vec{0}$, then the solution set of the system of equations $[A|\vec{b}]$ cannot be a plane through the origin.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is my proof complete? I feel like something is missing.

What I have written:

Consider $\vec{b} \in \mathbb{R}^3$, without loss of generality.

Then $[A|\vec{b}] = \begin{bmatrix}
a_1 & ... & a_{1n}|&b_1 \\
a_2 & ... & a_{2n}|&b_2 \\
a_3 & ... & a_{3n}|&b_3
\end{bmatrix}$

In order for the solution set to be a plane through the origin, $b_1 = b_2 = b_3 = 0$. However, $\vec{b}\neq\vec{0}$, so then $[A|\vec{b}]$ cannot be a plane through the origin.

Answer (score 1):

There's two significant problems I see:

- You're essentially just stating the contrapositive.  This is not a proof.
- You're assuming that $\vec{b} \in \mathbb{R}^3$.  So this would only prove a special case of the result you're asked to prove.

I suggest you start here:

If the solution set is a plane through the origin, then there is a solution to the system of equations, namely the all zero solution.  This implies that $A\vec{0}=\vec{b}$.  Do you see a problem with this?